# Masekhes Kesubos as "Shas Qatan"

Tags: talmud-gemara, maseches-kesubos

There is a [custom](http://steinsaltz.org/learning.php?pg=Daf_Yomi&articleId=743) of referring to Tractate Kesubos in the Bavli as "Shas Qatan", the Talmud in miniature. This is due to the fact that it treats of a wide variety of different topics, and includes a number of different sugyos that relate to sugyos brought in a number of other masekhtes. (In [this](http://dafyomireview2.com/ravkaplan/cdd/talmud/5774-Kesuvos/001-2013_10_07-RavKaplan-Kesubos_daf2a.mp3) lecture by Rav Nissan Kaplan, he mentions a number of these different sugyos by way of explaining why this masekhta is referred to in this fashion).

My question is two-fold:

- When did people first start referring to Tractate Kesubos as
  Shas Qatan? Was it Rishonim who did this?
- Does thinking of the masekhta in this fashion have any
  practical force? For example, were people encouraged to start with
  Kesubos because it can be seen as an introduction to all of Shas? Or
  was there ever the attitude that if a person can only learn one
  masekhta they should learn this one?

Comment: I found in Wikipedia this statement in name of Birke Yosef: מסכת זו מכונה גם בשם ש"ס קטן, כיוון שנידונים בה אגב העיון בהתחייבויות הכספיות בין בני הזוג עניינים רבים מהתלמוד כולו (כפי שציין ה"ברכי יוסף" על יורה דעה סימן רמ"ו), ובהם סוגיות יסודיות כגון חזקה, רוב, טענת מיגו טענת ברי ושמא ועוד נושאים רבים המהווים את יסודות המשפט העברי.

Comment: see also this link https://daf-yomi.com/Forums/Message.aspx?id=38692

Comment: +1 another theoretical practicality may be to use the sugya in kesubos as the main sugya in a situation where we don't know if we should rule in accordance with one of two sugyos.

Answer (score 14):

Masheches Kesuvos was called כולל תלמוד by the Shla's son (Rav Sheptel Horowitz author of ווי העמודים)  he wrote in his will to his children to first be fluent in these mashechtot : Brachos (inyan gadol), Shabbas (inyan Mefuar),and Kesuovos (kolel talumd). He refers to kesuvos as encapsalting the whole talmud. This is brought by the Chidah,and seems to be one of the first to mention such an idea.

Text of source:

[image]

Comment: This is a great source! Thank you. I'm not ticking it for the moment, in the hope that somebody can also bring information that answers my second question: whether or not thinking of this masekhta in this fashion carries any practical force.

Comment: @ShimonbM Doesn't the statement indicate that it is one of the most important masechtos to learn because it "includes the whole Talmud"?

Comment: Exactly what the Shla Hakadosh is saying ,that one should be fluent in it

Answer (score 7):

The authoritative (Hebrew) article on this topic is by Rabbi Tovia Preschel (found [here](http://www.toviapreschel.com/he/%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%9B%D7%AA-%D7%9B%D7%AA%D7%95%D7%91%D7%95%D7%AA-%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93-%D7%A7%D7%98%D7%9F/)).  He cites various very early sources that call Kesuvos "Shas Katan" or other similar names.

For example, he quotes the Hafla'ah, who says:

> בשגם כי מסכתא זו כוללת כל ענינים **והראשונים קראוה ש”ס קטן**

It was similarly known in a number of printings of Rishonim from the early 1700s.  He also devotes space to discussing the above source.

Also, see [this discussion](https://daf-yomi.com/Forums/Message.aspx?id=38692) which references an interesting Teshuvah from Chashukei Chemed, in which he connects Maseches Kesubos with the 13 Middos of Rachamim:

> מסכת כתובות מכוונת כנגד הי"ג מדות של רחמים
>
> שאלה אדם הלקוי במדת הכעס, רצה להנצל ממדה זו, ולכן רוצה לעסוק בתורה ביתר שאת וכמו שנאמר במסכת ברכות (דף ה ע"א) לעולם ירגיז אדם יצר טוב על יצר הרע, אם נצחו מוטב, ואם לאו יעסוק בתורה, איזה פרק בגמרא כדאי לו ללמוד?
>
> תשובה א. כדאי לו ללמוד את המקומות בגמרא העוסקים בגנות מדת הכעס כמו מסכת נדרים (דף כב ע"ב) יעו"ש באורך.
>
> ב. ילמד מסכת כתובות ובמיוחד פרק אף על פי, דהנה נאמר במדרש (אסתר רבה פרשה ט) ארבעה הם שפתחו באף, ואבדו באף, ואלו הן נחש ושר האופים ועדת קרח והמן, נחש דכתיב (בראשית ג) אף כי אמר אלקים, שר האופים דכתיב (בראשית מ) אף אני בחלומי, עדת קרח דכתיב (במדבר טז) אף לא אל ארץ, המן דכתיב אף לא הביאה אסתר המלכה, יעו"ש. ודקדק בספר שמן הטוב מה ראו רבותינו חכמי התלמוד הקדושים לפתוח ב'אף' בפרק אף על פי בכתובות. [וכן ראיתי ששאלה זו שאל רבינו החת"ס בהיותו נער, את בעל ההפלאה כשהתחילו ללמוד בישיבה מסכת כתובות]? ותירץ על פי מה דנודע כי התורה שבעל פה, שהם הי"ג מדות שהתורה נדרשת בהן, המה מכוונים כנגד הי"ג מדות של רחמים, ומסכת כתובות קראו הקדמונים ש"ס קטן, ובה נמצא י"ג פרקים, ופרק אף על פי הוא פרק החמישי, ומכוון כנגד מדת 'אפים', ולכך פיהם פתחו בחכמה, לפי שאף הוא נגד אפים, יעו"ש.
> ויתכן שיש בפרק זה אף סגולה להתגבר על מדת הכעס. וכמו כן יתכן שיש ללמוד מכאן שהרוצה לעורר על עצמו רחמי שמים, יש לו ללמוד מסכת כתובות שהוא מכוון כנגד הי"ג מדות של רחמים.

Comment: Glad you answered here. Unfortunately I don't read Hebrew. But it suffices for me to know there is a well-conceived answer.